# NodeJS, MySQL - Advanced query

Tags: mysql, node.js

**"Test"** table structure

- id
- value
- itemID

I want to check if in table **"Test"** there is an result with **itemID** = '123' and **value** = '456' **and whether it is the last added result ORDER BY id DESC**, I miss something in this code:

`SELECT * FROM Test WHERE itemID = '123' AND value= '456' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Could anyone help?

Comment: Might be helpful if you post what the response you're getting back is.  Is it a SQL error, or are you getting a different record from the one you want?  Also is your desired result a true/false value on if that result exists, or do you want to actually get the record back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> check if in table `Test` there is an result with `itemID = '123'` and `value = '456'` and whether it is the last added result ORDER BY id DESC

Your requirement can be litteraly translated as follows:

```
select *
from test t
where itemID = 123 and value = 456
and not exists (
    select 1
    from test t1
    where t1.id > t.id
)
```

The `NOT EXISTS` condition ensures that the record being selected is the latest, `id`-wise.

If the requirements are not satisfied, the query returns an empty resultset.

Another way to express it is to use a correlated subquery to get the latest id:

```
select *
from test t
where 
    itemID = 123 
    and value = 456
    and id = (select max(id) from test t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Sub query in where clause you can find it.

```
 SELECT t.* FROM `Test` as t WHERE `itemID` = 123 AND `value` = 456 AND `id` =(SELECT max(`id`) FROM Test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SELECT value 
          FROM Test 
         WHERE itemID = '123' 
         ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) = '456' AS it_matches;
```

The result will be one of these possibilities:

- 1 if the last "value" is 456, or
- 0 if the last "value" is another non-null value, or
- NULL if there are no rows with ItemID = 123 or the last row's "value" column is null.